# Mapeo con robot Pepper

Tags: mapa, robots.txt

Estoy utilizando el robot Pepper [1](https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/pepper) para realizar el mapeo de una determinada zona y de donde he obtenido un archivo con una extensión .txt. Este archivo no se cómo interpretarlo. ¿Alguien por casualidad sabría como interpretarlo? Adjunto a continuación, unas primeras lineas de este archivo:

```
22 serialization::archive 15 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 2.018050432e+00 -3.136447668e+00 0 1.940492630e+00 -3.095751524e+00 0 2.208060026e+00 -3.014304161e+00 0 2.404366016e+00 -2.997698545e+00 0 2.118302107e+00 -2.879838705e+00 0 2.517558336e+00 -2.869279623e+00 0 2.113639593e+00 -2.808968306e+00 0 1.717097044e+00 -2.749679327e+00 0 1.839792728e+00 -2.644454956e+00 0 1.810475349e+00 -2.585330486e+00 0 1.850159407e+00 -2.506272316e+00 0 2.105285883e+00 -2.444391727e+00 0 1.783310175e+00 -2.373553753e+00 0 1.784146428e+00 -2.310865641e+00 0 2.031968355e+00 -2.293570518e+00 0 1.638949037e+00 -2.225256443e+00 0 2.007625818e+00 -2.135352373e+00 0 2.424630165e+00 -2.087579012e+00 0 2.385181665e+00 -2.014414549e+00 0 2.678976059e+00 -1.936586976e+00 0 3.015558958e+00 -1.887816310e+00 0 3.454950809e+00 -1.812269092e+00 0 3.000000000e+00 -1.745192885e+00 1 3.000000000e+00 -1.682361007e+00 1 2.385307074e+00 -1.681436896e+00 0 2.483392000e+00 -1.619278908e+00 0 1.043090105e+00 -1.498038173e+00 0 1.140123844e+00 -1.475869536e+00 0 8.171656728e-01 -1.382030964e+00 0 8.117251992e-01 -1.320994258e+00 0 8.093428612e-01 -1.259366512e+00 0 1.209775567e+00 -1.212461352e+00 0 9.133222103e-01 -1.147818089e+00 0 1.223507643e+00 -1.089609861e+00 0 6.731874943e-01 -1.038536906e+00 0 6.371002197e-01 -9.456509352e-01 0 6.534790397e-01 -8.724189997e-01 0 1.526357174e+00 -8.482295275e-01 0 1.478241086e+00 -7.596688271e-01 0 1.527243733e+00 -7.016450167e-01 0 2.385743618e+00 -6.730573177e-01 0 2.139214039e+00 -5.973693132e-01 0 1.094123721e+00 -5.042370558e-01 0 7.396064401e-01 -4.311778247e-01 0 7.766309977e-01 -3.868364394e-01 0 3.000000000e+00 -3.000603616e-01 1 1.117124796e+00 -2.485528886e-01 0 1.022244573e+00 -1.932025254e-01 0 5.957378149e-01 -1.219336092e-01 0 1.468697667e+00 -9.947410226e-02 0 5.757434964e-01 -4.366204143e-02 0 1.541685581e+00 5.959582329e-02 0 1.469289541e+00 1.162116230e-01 0 2.528434038e+00 1.456189901e-01 0 8.930852413e-01 2.056468725e-01 0 2.237164736e+00 3.017804027e-01 0 2.238222122e+00 3.688246608e-01 0 2.398496151e+00 4.288119972e-01 0 1.612808824e+00 5.095385909e-01 0 1.585297465e+00 5.773227215e-01 0 1.536889553e+00 5.853421688e-01 0 1.692812920e+00 6.847494841e-01 0 1.572824955e+00 7.478654981e-01 0 1.571875811e+00 8.189838529e-01 0 3.000000000e+00 8.937448263e-01 1 1.273902535e+00 9.488269091e-01 0 1.264225721e+00 1.004029155e+00 0 1.225613713e+00 1.029549479e+00 0 1.327350974e+00 1.115995646e+00 0 7.979446054e-01 1.161874413e+00 0 8.044592738e-01 1.249783635e+00 0 7.752525210e-01 1.301178455e+00 0 7.482502460e-01 1.356437564e+00 0 7.683212161e-01 1.445890427e+00 0 7.477830648e-01 1.506042004e+00 0 7.300968766e-01 1.569347024e+00 0 7.775722146e-01 1.590167642e+00 0 7.638589144e-01 1.652567506e+00 0 7.532213330e-01 1.716987252e+00 0 7.457910776e-01 1.782969832e+00 0 7.916083336e-01 1.853080392e+00 0 7.908892035e-01 1.916275620e+00 0 3.000000000e+00 2.024718285e+00 1 1.152445793e+00 2.041511774e+00 0 1.170835257e+00 2.126156569e+00 0 7.709578276e-01 2.179811478e+00 0 1.102463126e+00 2.235172272e+00 0 1.073643208e+00 2.294531584e+00 0 1.205648303e+00 2.339133501e+00 0 1.251523852e+00 2.411486149e+00 0 1.123201013e+00 2.477010727e+00 0 1.180806637e+00 2.548003197e+00 0 1.243795991e+00 2.612102747e+00 0 1.382096648e+00 2.670560598e+00 0 1.278850913e+00 2.752430439e+00 0 1.496349454e+00 2.789956093e+00 0 1.476404309e+00 2.863986731e+00 0 1.670866370e+00 2.907567263e+00 0 1.864008307e+00 3.001902819e+00 0 1.801331520e+00 3.076291084e+00 0 3.000000000e+00 0 0 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0 0 15791734524392 0 0 0 2 120 5.000000075e-02 0 0 -3.000000000e+00 3.000000000e+00 2.500000000e-01 1186 0 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 0 0 0 13 73 72 68 82 0 0 0 120 0 0 0 120 8 0 0 0 0 28 15 105 14 0 0 4 105 73 68 65 84 104 5 197 193 223 170 92 103 29 199 225 207 239 14 172 104 105 33 13 149 66 146 182 39 251 86 246 129 180 169 32 141 169 7 98 192 75 248 254 190 247 208 30 154 22 196 3 73 112 110 101 36 81 218 80 136 141 66 161 130 120 5 141 107 205 158 53 51 107 246 250 243 238 53 3 239 243 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 82 71 36 117 68 114 22 122 239 215 220 72 36 103 33 204 134 238 221 167 68 36 231 32 44 211 16 96 100 230 68 114 83 143 127 195 53 130 119 131 79 17 141 123 95 243 193 71 244 200 28 137 228 102 30 127 135 57 38 54 44 58 230 128 192 171 75 122 34 185 17 209 48 71 68 203 136 45 179 39 90 166 47 146 114 50 162 97 250 68 203 136 142 233 136 43 166 47 146 66 95 189 124 247 159 220 126 69 203 244 136 150 197 206 221 184 79 75 92 49 199 34 41 36 26 239 252 139 150 217 248 252 17 45 209 178 56 116 239 62 136 206 197 37 71 34 41 37 246 252 5 63 6 175 137 215 17 252 64 195 98 138 57 18 73 33 221 126 197 56 139 73 230 72 36 179 254 244 173 249 234 199 239 232 252 252 63 220 216 197 37 125 145 204 19 167 51 125 145 204 16 22 51 44 230 152 190 72 1
```

Comment: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146704) tienes una explicación de los primeros caracteres. a partir de ahi, son los datos propiamente dichos que aparentemente son simplemente coordenadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!